# Sql Import from excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

Hopefully someone can shed some light on my problem. I am importing an excel file to a ms sql table and any values that are .1 in excel import to the table as .09999. Can someone explain why this happens and how I can get them to show as .1 instead.

The query I run is

```
select * from POSCustomer where LoyaltyID <> ''
```

Comment: If you could show us the code used, we might point out where's the precision leakage

Comment: select * from POSCustomer where LoyaltyID <> ''     and copy the two columns I need to an excel file and then import through sql

Comment: please edit your question and add the code. Try to avoid putting code in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check source file - Excel. Excel by default will round numbers like 0.0999 to 0.1

However Real number precision is different as displayed precision. In the cell the number is still 0.0999, even you can see it nicely rounded to 0.1. If any tool is importing excel it will import number with "real" precision.

[image]

If this is your case, then solution is to make excel to set precision as displayed. Set cell number format to number and set precision to one decimal places. Then go to Excel >> `File` >> `Options` >> `Advanced` >> Thick Set `precision as displayed` [Save]

Warning - with this approach you permanently lose data information. You wont be able to retrieve #.#99999 back, it will be lost.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are importing into SQL, do you have an ADO routine or are you outputting a file for a bulk insert?

If through code then round the number to 1dp on the way through, if through a text file then round it before you output it through the round formula.

Comment: Like this. Given the way Excel stores numerical values, rounding values to a certain number of decimal places should do.